# Apache rewrite rule with 1 AND and 8 OR conditions

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a situation where I need to apply 8 rewritecond in apache and exclude 1 IP from those 8 conditions.
By default, the Rewrite condition follow [AND].
Now, how do I write the rule:

```
A [AND] (B [OR] C [OR] D [OR] E [OR] F [OR] G [OR] H [OR] I)
```

Let me know in case my question is not clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please place parentheses around the conditions so we know what goes with what. Also please break it into several lines. For instance, do you want `(A [AND] B ) [OR] C [OR] D [OR] E [OR] F [OR] G [OR] H [OR] I`, or `A [AND] ( B [OR] C [OR] D [OR] E [OR] F [OR] G [OR] H [OR] I)`... Same for the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `[OR]` conditions first. Here is an example :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /a/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /b/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /c/ [OR]
(...)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /y/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /z/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/glossary/
RewriteRule ^/glossary/([a-z])/ glossary.php?letter=$1 [L]
```

With explicit parenthesis, you've got this :

```
(((((((B [OR] C) [OR] D) [OR] E) [OR] F) [OR] G) [OR] H) [OR] I) [AND] A
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and let you know!

Comment: My requirement changed, so could not try your solution. Sorry!

Comment: Ok, whatever your new requirements, if this post answers your original question, you can set is as accepted. You can test it [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) if you want. And if you've got a new issue with new requirements, feel free to ask another question.